# "The system cannot find the file specified" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I was trying to run Kotlin program in my Android Studio.
I have created a project. The app builds and runs perfectly, but when I try to create a separate .kt file and run it, it shows the error -

> Error running 'abcKt': Cannot run program
> "C:\Users\user\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_362\bin\java.exe" (in directory
> "D:\path"): CreateProcess error=2, The system
> cannot find the file specified

The file name is abc.kt and its a basic hello world program with `fun main()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically this was happening because multiple Gradle daemons were spawned because **JDK and JAVA_HOME locations were different**.

Solution 1: Set the JDK location same as JAVA_HOME location.
Solution 2: Set the JAVA_HOME location same as JDK location.

What I did? (Solution 1)

1. Look for `Environment Variables` in your PC settings.
2. Copy the `JAVA_HOME` variable `value`(which is the path for JAVA_HOME).
3. Use the Keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (in Android Studio)  to search for IDE Commands.
4. Type `Change Gradle JDK Location`
5. Paste that path in `Gradle user home`.
6. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.